# Is it possible to chr() a string?

Tags: python, unicode, cryptography

I am sure this question has already been asked, so forgive me for the duplicate.

Python's `chr()` function returns the unicode string representation of 1 ordinal value. How can I return a unicode string of a string of ordinals? For example:

john:

 j - 106

 o - 111

 h - 104

 n - 110

The full unicode string is: `106111104110`

My current method is:

```
from textwrap import wrap
ct = "106111104110" # unicode string
Split = wrap(ct,3) # split into threes list
inInt = list(map(int, Split)) # convert list of string into list of int
answer=''.join([chr(num) for num in inInt]) # return unicode string for each 3 character string
print(answer)
```

The above works correctly, printing "john".

However this does not work when the unicode for the value is less than 3 characters, or less than 100. For example:

apple:

 a - 97

 p - 112

 p - 112

 l - 108

 e - 101

The full unicode string is: `97112112108101`

However doing:

```
ct="97112112108101"
Split = wrap(ct,3) 
inInt = list(map(int, Split)) 
answer=''.join([chr(num) for num in inInt]) 
print(answer)
```

will print `ϋyyQ` because the unicode of `a` is 97, which is only 2 characters. I would like to not be constricted to using only characters over 100.

Is there a python library that has the functionality I am looking for? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How even did it happen that you are given concatenated codepoints?

Comment: As you have already found out, this is not possible. Values like "97112112108101" are not a suitable format to represent strings unambiguously.

Comment: Try to walk yourself through some arbitrary examples. Keep in mind that unicode can have a lot more than 3 digits per number. You may want to consider a different encoding scheme. Something like what UTF-8 does in binary, perhaps?

Comment: I have a feeling that, if you told us where `ct` is coming from, someone may be able to suggest a better, alternative approach.

Comment: `ct` is being made by me. Sorry for not adding the crypto tag. I think I will choose an alternative approach as this is not possible. Thank you @mkrieger1.

Comment: The standard way of doing this is to use utf-8 encoding to convert between strings and bytes. If `s` is a `str` then `b=s.encode('utf-8')` returns a `bytes` object containing the utf-8 encoding of `s`. Then `s == b.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode code points can be up to six hexadecimal digits or seven decimal digits, so you could use leading zeros for consistency:

```
>>> ''.join(format(ord(x),'06x') for x in 'john')
'00006a00006f00006800006e'
>>> ''.join(chr(int(_[i:i+6],16)) for i in range(0,len(_),6))  # _ gets previous result from REPL.
'john'
>>> ''.join(format(ord(x),'06x') for x in '你好吗')
'004f6000597d005417'
>>> ''.join(chr(int(_[i:i+6],16)) for i in range(0,len(_),6))
'你好吗'
```

However, typical encoding is performed on byte strings, so encode to UTF-8 first, then you can use `bytes` methods to get two-digit hex strings:

```
>>> 'apple'.encode('utf8').hex()
'6170706c65'
>>> bytes.fromhex(_).decode()
'apple'
>>> '你好吗'.encode('utf8').hex()
'e4bda0e5a5bde59097'
>>> bytes.fromhex(_).decode('utf8')
'你好吗'
```